# which page/code renders admin/config in drupal 7

Tags: 7

I have a very basic question. In my drupal 7 installation when I go to `admin/config` the page does not render and all I get is a `1` printed out. I am sure someone die a `die()` on this page. But I am not sure which page is loaded when `admin/config` is rendered. Can anyone point me which possible page/code I should be looking at?

Comment: did you read this post about WSOD, http://drupal.org/node/158043

Answer (score 2):

The page that normally come up when the path is `admin/config` is inserted into the site by the core **system** module's implementation of [`hook_menu()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_menu/7).

The callback function that actually produces the page is [`system_admin_config_page()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.admin.inc/function/system_admin_config_page/7).

However, unless you (or somebody else) has hacked core (and we **don't** that, right?) these functions are not the cause of the problem.

Here's a link to the SOP for debugging [Blank pages or "white screen of death" (WSOD)](https://drupal.org/node/158043).

Answer (score 0):

if you think you may have put a die() in somewhere and forgotten where, here's a nice grep command to search files for a string.

```
grep -rHin 'die()' *
```

…and run this from the command line, it will search recursively through directories.